# 8-digit multiplication by 6 with unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been maths competition mock tests and this is a question that I do not know how to do:
[image]
All I know is that the hundred millions place value on the right is between $1$ and $5$(this is because that the largest possible number on the left($98754321$) times $6$ makes $592525926$ and the hundred millions digit is still $5$.) and that the units place on the right is even.

How do I find what numbers are in the boxes?

Comment: I guess the best way to tackle this is to make a few observations and hope for the best. First, note that the right-hand side must be divisible by 6. I suspect that the fact the 9 digits on the right hand side being distinct will be important and the same applies to the fact that 6 is not used on the left-hand side.

Comment: @user328442 Any even number whose digits are a permutation of $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ is divisible by $6$, in fact divisible by $18$ (consider the digital root), so that observation doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

Using a computer search, I find $87$ solutions, of which the least is
$$  21578943 \times 6 =  129473658$$
and the greatest is
$$ 98745231 \times 6 = 592471386$$

I'd hate to tackle this by hand.